# return user details after ldap authentication (asp.net vb)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, active-directory, ldap

Afternoon all!
I am trying to set up a new internal system for my client currently, they insisted on integrating the login with AD, which makes sense, and i have managed that with no problem.

However what i also want to do, after authentication, is to store some user details / attributes as session variables.

I have the following code to aithenticate the user:

```
'this function authenticates against AD - very simple and works nicely.
Function AuthenticateUser(path As String, user As String, pass As String) As Boolean
    Dim de As New DirectoryEntry(path, user, pass, AuthenticationTypes.Secure)
    Try
        'run a search using those credentials.  
        'If it returns anything, then you're authenticated
        Dim ds As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(de)
        ds.FindOne()

        Return True
    Catch
        'otherwise, it will crash out so return false
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

which works nicely, and once the function returns me a True, i set Session("LoggedIn") as True.

what i need to do is (hopefully within the above function) save the user's name, and 2 other custom atributes from within the user's AD profile.

How would i access those (hypothetically)

Comment: I have the same code, but I'm having trouble getting it working. Any chance you could provide me with and example or what your parameters are (let's user domain kevinland.org, user jeremy, password humbug)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DirectorySearcher` constructor that supports retrieving properties. Add the attributes the LDAP client requires to the constructor.

#### see also

- [DirectorySearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx)

Comment: Hi Terry, do you mean DirectoryServer or DirectorySearcher? i cant find any reference to DirectoryServer in .NET 4...